# how to show both icon and text on button on mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

Code Used:

```
m_pButton->Create(L"ABC", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| BM_SETIMAGE,CRect(0,0,100,100),this,ID_BUTTON1);

m_pButton->SetIcon(::LoadIcon(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1)));
```

//above Code show neither showing image nor showing text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BM_SETIMAGE is not a button style, but a message which is sent to the window in order to set a bitmap.
What you probably want is the BS_BITMAP style. Unfortunately as far as I know, it is not possible to have both text and a bitmap on a standard button. But you should find plenty of working implementations of a custom button class on sites like codeguru or codeproject.

Answer (score 3):

You might use [CMFCButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983153.aspx) if you are using VS 2008 SP1 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

**BS_ICON** and **BS_BITMAP** must be both unset to enable icon and text on the same button.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761822(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

WPF might be able to do this.  But, changing GUI topkits might not be an option anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `DrawItem` method in CButton. For details check out the following links:

[CButton::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0k9f0a4%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Owner drawn button - step by step](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/buttonctrl/article.php/c5157)